# Generics and Abstract Methods

Tags: java, generics

I've come across something I find odd in Java and haven't been able to find much information on it. Consider the following code:

```
public class TestClass {

    private static abstract class AbstractClass {
        abstract List<? extends Object> getList();
        abstract Map<Long, List<? extends Object>> getMap();
    }

    private static final class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass {
        @Override
        List<String> getList() { 
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        Map<Long, List<String>> getMap() {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler shows an error on the `getMap()` method:

```
getMap() in ConcreteClass cannot override getMap() in AbstractClass
  return type Map<Long, List<String>> is not compatible with Map<Long, List<? extends Object>>
```

But the same error is not present for the `getList()` method, yet I would expect either both to work or both to fail. In both cases, the overriding method is delcaring `List<String>` in place of `List<? extends Object>`. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because there exists an implicit conversion from `List<String>` to `List<? extends Object>`, but not from `Map<Long, List<String>>` to `Map<Long, List<? extends Object>>`.

All generic types are invariant unless you're using wildcard types. Since there is no wildcard in the "outer" Map type's generic type arguments, it can't capture any generic type that doesn't match exactly.

If your map type were `Map<Long, ? extends List<? extends Object>>` then it would work like you expect.

And the other part if the answer is that subclasses can override or implement a supertype method with a different return type, but only if the return type of the subtype's method is implicitly convertible to the supertype method's return type. (In Java 1.4 and below even that wouldn't work: it would be a compile time error if the types didn't match exactly.)

Comment: Great answer, thanks! (I'll accept after the time limit is up)

Comment: the good point, I'd like to add `? extends Object` may be replaced with `?` without any effect

Comment: @Andrew: sure, but the same principle applies for any lower bound on the wildcard, not just `Object`.

Comment: Using the word "outer" seems confusing and inaccurate here, the only outer class doesn't really matter for purposes of this example.

Comment: @Nathan: by "outer" here I'm referring to the `Map<K, V>` generic type, not the "inner" types that `K` and `V` are instantiated with. Is there a better terminology to use for that?